# How to plot strings in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to create a plot in MATLAB with the following features:

- On the x-axis I want to have 4 different strings: `['string1','string2','string3','string4']`
- I want each of these strings to have 2 substrings: `['sub1','sub2']`
  but I want them to be displayed above the main strings, that would make them a 'sur-string' ? I hope you know what I mean.
- Then on the y-axis, I want to plot 3 different types of data to every sub-string.

I figured, maybe it is possible to realize this with a stem-plot. I would then have 3 stems at every sub-string. That makes 6 at every string. What diagram is fit best to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [text](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) command to get the strings on the x-axis

```
stem(rand(4,1));
set(gca, 'XTick', [1:4], 'XTickLabel', cell(10,1), 'YLim', [0 1]);
text(1, -.05, {'above string 1', 'above string 1', 'string 1'}, 'FontSize', 10, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center');
text(2, -.05, {'above string 2', 'above string 2', 'string 2'}, 'FontSize', 10, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center');
text(3, -.05, {'above string 3', 'above string 3', 'string 3'}, 'FontSize', 10, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center');
text(4, -.05, {'above string 4', 'above string 4', 'string 4'}, 'FontSize', 10, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center');
```

[image: stem plot]

To plot stems from the y axis you could rotate the plot frame using [view](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) command like this:

```
% plot some data
stem([1:3], 'LineWidth', 2);

% set the x axis which will be the y axis after the rotation
set(gca, 'XLim', [1 3], 'XTick', [1:3], 'XTickLabel', cell(3,1));
text(1.1, -.25, {'another y string 1', 'above y string 1', 'y string 1'}, 'FontSize', 10, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center');
text(2, -.25, {'another y string 2', 'above y string 2', 'y string 2'}, 'FontSize', 10, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center');
text(3, -.25, {'another y string 3', 'above y string 3', 'y string 3'}, 'FontSize', 10, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center');

% set the y axis which will be the x axis after the rotation
set(gca, 'YLim', [0 3], 'YTick', [1:4], 'YTickLabel', cell(10,1));
text(0.9, 0, {'above string 1', 'above string 1', 'string 1'}, 'FontSize', 10, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center');
text(0.9, 1, {'above string 2', 'above string 2', 'string 2'}, 'FontSize', 10, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center');
text(0.9, 2, {'above string 3', 'above string 3', 'string 3'}, 'FontSize', 10, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center');
text(0.9, 3, {'above string 4', 'above string 4', 'string 4'}, 'FontSize', 10, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center');

% rotate the view
view(90,-90)
```

[image: rotated stems]